# How can I get playonlinux to download?

Tags: linux, playonlinux

I am trying to download playonlinux but every time I attempt to I always get the same error
Package playonlinux is not available but is referred to as another package. This may mean the package is missing, has been obsoleted or is only available from another source E: Package is only available from another source.
I am on Crostini is there any way to get it to work and yes I do have wine installed.

Comment: Could you not just get it directly from github?

Comment: Possibly related: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/208664/cannot-install-wine-and-playonlinux

Comment: I’m not familiar with Crostini, but the error message suggests it’s using `apt`; what does `/etc/apt/sources.list` contain? What about any files in `/etc/apt/sources.list.d`?